# How to achieve parameterization similar to CsvDataSetConfig using UserDefinedVariables Control In JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, parameterization

**In JMeter**, I need to parameterize sequence of inter-linked values using **"UserDefinedVariables"** control. I am able to achieve the same with **"CSVDataSetConfig"**, but I need to use "UserDefinedVariables" as I have only two rows of input data which I am sending to my API request and i will repeat the same values for further iterations.

**Example:**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

Iteration 1: Yasir,Nisha,India

Iteration 2: Azar,Riya,Dubai

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [User Parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) is what you're looking for:

[image]

You will get something like:

[image]

More information: [JMeter Parameterization: The Complete Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization)

Comment: Thanks Much Dmitri.. you are always my hope :-).
but if i use UserParameter and design above, when i run with 1 user and multiple iterations and it always picking up the same value. Can u suggest on this?